# How can I disable TRadioButtons on a panel without changing their appearance?

Tags: radio-button, delphi-2009

**The scenario**

I have a reasonably complex form that is used for either data entry or for viewing with no editing allowed, depending upon a state variable (the colour and headings on the form change depending upon the state). It contains many panels containing data entry type components. When in the viewing (non editing) state these panels are set to disabled, so preventing any of the components they contain from being changed.

One panel contains four TRadioButtons and a memo box with scroll bars.
Because of the amount of text in the memo I still want to be able to scroll the memo box when in view mode in order to read it all. However I do not want either the memo text or the radio buttons to be changed.

**What I have tried**

Instead of disabling the whole panel I leave it enabled and just make the memo box read only. This allows scrolling but not editing of the memobox as desired.

However as the panel is enabled it means the radiobuttons are also enabled and can be changed.

If I set the enabled property of each radiobutton to false I can prevent them being changed as desired but this also changes their appearance and greys them out.

**Question**

How can I prevent a user from changing the radiobuttons on this panel whilst keeping their appearance unchanged as if they are enabled i.e. without them greying out?

**Minimal reproducible example**

```
procedure TFrmMember.ShowMemberForm(MemberDisplayMode: TMemberDisplayType);
begin
case FormDisplayMode of

<other stuff in a big case statement depending upon MemberDisplayMode>

ShowNoEdit: begin
            SetFormDisplay(ShowNoEdit);  //set colours and titles etc
            DisableAllControls;          //disable all panels on the form

            //now enable scrolling of the comment memo content but don't allow edits
            PanelComment.Enabled := True;  //enable the panel containing the memo and 4 radiobuttons
            MemoComment.ReadOnly := True;  //don't allow editing of the memo

            //now disable the radio buttons -THIS CHANGES APPEARANCE ??
            RadioButtonCircEmail.Enabled := False;
            RadioButtonCircPost.Enabled := False;
            RadioButtonCircBoth.Enabled := False;
            RadioButtonCircNone.Enabled := False;

            <other stuff>
            end;

    <other stuff in a big case statement depending upon MemberDisplayMode>
    end; //case

end; //procedure ShowMemberForm
```

Comment: What about changing the OnClick event handler so that it always force/restore to value from data model?

Comment: If not greyed out then won't the user expect to be able to edit the values?

Comment: There already is a single OnClick event, called by every radiobutton, that performs other functions but I suppose I could add code to it with a case statement to detect which button was clicked. How would I detect which button had been checked before a click occurred on another button though?

Comment: I take your point about the greying out but it doesn't look very nice as it's hard to read the button text against the coloured panel background. They shouldn't expect to edit as they would have already previously selected to view the data without editing (or will have been forced to by their log on status), the form colour is different and consistent with non editing and there is a big heading saying 'Viewing Only, No Edits'

Comment: Oh, and the form will have no 'Save' button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a `TPanel` on the existing Panel and move the RadioButtons to this new Panel.  Or, use a single `TRadioGroup` instead of placing individual buttons on a Panel.

Then you can disable just the new Panel/Group, while keeping the parent Panel enabled and setting the `TMemo` to read-only.

Comment: Thank you Remy, As usual, after posting the question and going to have a coffee and a longer think, I came up with exactly this same workaround answer myself. I'll accept your answer though as you took the trouble to post it.